# How to use DT table's row selection and plotting when pivoting the data

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a dataset that looks like this.
*There is also another column called "report_date" in my data that I did not include it in the df          above as it will be a shiny filter.
I am trying to write a shiny app that couples a DT::datatable with two plots so that when a user      selects a row in the table, one group barplot and line plot are displayed for every Name/row in the  table.
[here are my shiny filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fL2hW.png)
My problem:
I need the table output to be presented wide (just like the table shown above) but to be able to    plot   data   in group bar charts, I have to pivot my data from wide to long. Doing this, when a row in the wide   table is selected, I get the row in the long data visualized in the plotted outputs which is not   what I   want.
I was initially looking for a way that allows me to plot data row by row depending on the user   selection so that I can have both the table and plot outputs presented in wide format. But all my attempts failed.
[This is the output I'm expecting:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdrRm.png)`
Below is the code I have tried which is from the page below:
[Select rows from one table to another then plot the data from the second table R Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71144962/select-rows-from-one-table-to-another-then-plot-the-)   data-from-the-second-table-r
Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers

```
    library(shiny)
    library(DT)

    df <- tibble(
      Name = c("Sarah", "Mark", "Peter"),
      Cash = c("0.31%", "$69b", "12.5%"), 
      Card = c("0.54%", "$2b", "80.7%"), 
      Debt = c("0.20%", "$14b", "17%")) %>% 
    as.data.frame()

    df <- reactive ({df)}
    df1() <- df() %>% pivot_longer(c(2:4), names_to = "category", values_to = "value")

    server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    
      output$x1 = DT::renderDataTable(df(), server = FALSE)
    
      output$x2 = DT::renderDataTable({
          sel <- input$x1_rows_selected
          if(length(df())){
              df()[sel, ]
          }
        
        }, server = FALSE)  
      output$x3 <- renderPlot({
          s = input$x1_rows_selected
          ggplot(df1()[input$x1_rows_selected, ], aes(x=category, y= value)) +
              geom_line()
      })

      output$x4 <- renderPlot({
          s = input$x1_rows_selected
          ggplot(df1()[input$x1_rows_selected, ], aes(x=report_date, y= value)) +
              geom_line()
      })

  })


    ui <- fluidPage(
    
      fluidRow(
         column(6, DT::dataTableOutput('x1')),
         column(6, DT::dataTableOutput('x2')),
         column(6, plotOutput('x3', height = 500))
         column(6, plotOutput('x4', height = 500))
     )
    
 )

    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Please share sample data (using dput or data.frame).